# Angular 6 auxiliary routerLink not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular6

I've configured the routes & created auxiliary router-outlets in my component & but I'm not able to either go to the URL path nor bind it through routerLink.

My root component of named router works just fine, but the other ones are not getting accessed. Below is the code for reference, suggestion for solutions are welcome.

Any attempt to access the route lands to the app home page. I even manually  tried to access it like: 
http://localhost:4200/profile/projects(rightpanel:addtask)
http://localhost:4200/profile/projects/(rightpanel:addtask)
http://localhost:4200/profile/projects/projaddedit/(rightpanel:addtask)

but nothing works, even in routerlink I tried like, it didn't help either:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { rightpanel: 'addtask' }}]" class="btn">Link to Add Task</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/profile/projects', { outlets: { rightpanel: 'addtask' }}]" class="btn">Link to Add Task</a>
```

**ROUTER COMPONENT:**

```
<split-area size="40">
    <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
</split-area>

<split-area size="60">
    <a [routerLink]="['/profile/project', {outlets: {rightpanel: 'addmilestone'}}]">Go to Adds Milestone</a>
    <router-outlet name="rightpanel"></router-outlet>
</split-area>
```

**ROUTER CONFIG:**

```
   const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '', component: ProjectsComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './proj-list/proj-list.module#ProjListModule',
          },
          {
            path: 'projaddedit',
            loadChildren: './proj-add-edit/proj-add-edit.module#ProjAddEditModule',
          },
          {
            path: 'subproj',
            component: SubProjComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'resources',
            component: ResourcesComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: AddMilestoneComponent,
            outlet: 'rightpanel'
          },
          {
            path: 'addmilestone',
            component: ProjDetailsComponent,
            outlet: 'rightpanel'
          },
          {
            path: 'addtask',
            component: AddTaskComponent,
            outlet: 'rightpanel'
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

Comment: Did you add that routes array to .forRoot

Comment: I've added .forChild(routes) since it's a child route.                     @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProjectsRoutingModule { }

Comment: You have a .forRoot somewhere and you're importing this module with .forChild into it somewhere?